# route add command does not work on bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, route

I have some `route add` commands to run on Ubuntu. It works when I copy the command and paste it on the terminal. But I've tried to create a bash script which looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo route add -net 'someIp' netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 'anotherIp' 
sudo route add -net 'someOtherIp' netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 'anotherIp'
```

But when I run it. the output is:

```
SIOCADDRT: Dispositivo inexistente
```

which can be translated to `SIOCADDRT: device does not exist`

I've run `chmod +x` on the file and tried running the script with sudo but it did not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please make sure that you are not trying to add an already existent route.

SIOCADDRT: device does not exist

SIOC: Serial Input Output Controller.
ADD: ADD (addition).
RT: RouTe (routing ip).
File exists – Routing is already configured so delete wrong one and add the new one.

Comment: That is probably the issue, because when I copy the commands and paste it, sometimes a warning shows up. But I still don't get why it does not add the missing routes when the script is running but it does get added when I copy the same commands and paste it on the terminal. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: can you add the interface name after the command in the script and test it, please?
EXAMPLE: sudo route add -net 'someIp' netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 'anotherIp' eth0

Comment: It outputs the same result as before

Comment: did you remove the already created rules before executing the script? Also, the rules that are being add shouldn´t overlap existing ones.

Comment: Yes. To be sure of that I've tried it after rebooting the system. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days, I finally found the problem. At first, I hadn't added the `#!/bin/bash` to the script, but after I added it, it was still not working. Then I found this [post(in Portuguese)](https://terminalroot.com.br/2014/09/resolvendo-bad-interpreter-no-bash.html) explaining that the problem could be some invisible characters on the file, which makes sense because I had converted it from a `.bat` file manually. So I just had to run `sed -i 's/\r$//' routes.sh` and everything started working.